# How can I cut up a raster image in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pathfinder

I want to split this apple (jpeg) into pieces along the outline I've created over it. I created and edited a pie chart/graph for the lines, then edited it to conform to the apple shape. I want to be able to show one piece of the "pie" at a time as a separate image. I tried `path > divide` objects below and all of the pathfinder combinations I could. I used the graph tool to create the "pie" and edited it by hand to conform it to the apple shape.

[image]

Comment: [Why was my question downvoted](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2632/why-was-my-question-downvoted-and-or-closed)

Comment: Sorry - just added the picture :)

Comment: The image helps understand what you are working with but what have you tried? Why is that not working?  How are things constructed? I added the Illustrator tag, but I'm guessing since you used the pathfinder tag. Is it all vector or is it raster or a combination? You've left **a lot** of unknowns in the question.

Comment: The apple is a jpeg. I tried path > divide objects below and all of the pathfinder combinations I could. I used the graph tool to create the "pie" and edited it by hand to conform it to the apple shape.

Comment: Hi Megan, please click the [edit](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/54455/edit) link and add information to the question. The more information you can add, the more likely you are to get accurate and helpful answers. Thanks! FYI, Pathfinder will **not** work with raster images.

Comment: If the image is a JPG, illustrator isn't really the right tool for this. You want to be using a raster tool like Photoshop (or, alternatively, auto-trace the JPG in Illustrator you have vector shapes to work with).

Answer (score 2):

With Adobe Illustrator you **can not** cut up raster images, such as jpgs. Illustrator just does not work that way.

- You can use copies of the raster image and create [clipping masks](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/clipping-masks.html) or [opacity masks](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/how-to/illustrator-opacity-masks-transparency.html).
- You can use software designed to work with raster images, such as Photoshop
- You can [trace](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/image-trace.html) the raster image in Illustrator, converting it to vector and then adjust the vector objects
- You can use third party ($$) Illustrator plugins like [Rasterino](http://www.astutegraphics.com/software/rasterino/)

In short, what you are trying to do, you can't if the image is raster. Pathfinder does **not** function with raster images.

Answer (score 2):

Illustrator is not designed to work with raster images but if you need to cut the image up. You can do like scott said and use a clipping mask.

You can use your existing lines. I used the `pen tool` to outline the shape.

[image: apple 1]

I then selected both the apple jpg and the path I just created.

Go to the transparency panel and select `clip`

[image: apple clip]

the end result

[image: clipped apple]

This is not the best approach but it is a way to "split" the image.

> Note: If doing this, then you would need to copy the original image
>   for each cutout you do.