# How to split or cut image object in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, images, path

How to split or cut raster image object that was placed in Adobe Illustrator?

The *Knife Tool* doesn't work on raster images.

Comment: I'm afraid we may need a bit more to go on. There's the Knife Tool, The Scissors Tool, Pathfinder, Pen Tool,  Masks.. so many things. Which one to use depends upon what *specifically* you need to do.

Comment: You cannot slice images. But you can use clipping masks to fake the cuts.

Comment: @LeoNas you can slice images in the general sense of "slice". You can't use the Knife tool on raster images though. `:)`

Comment: I mean slice images using the knife tool.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/54455/how-can-i-cut-up-a-raster-image-in-illustrator

Answer (score 5):

Images can't be cut  using standard tools in Illustrator because it is a Vector editing software. (Your images are raster)

Your options are (ordered from most ideal to least)

- Use a clipping masks.
- Use Photoshop (or other Raster editing software)
- Use autotrace to make the image Vector and then you can cut it how you like (problem is, you'll have many paths)